# Glossaries package, Multiple glossaries mixing up entries

Tags: pdftex, glossaries

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=red
}

\usepackage[nopostdot,acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,nomain]{glossaries}

\newglossary[tld]{type1}{pref1}{ntn}{Title One}
\newglossary[tld]{type2}{pref2}{ntn}{Title Two}
\newglossary[tld]{type3}{pref3}{ntn}{Title Three}
\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{pref1:testone}{
                type=type1,
                name={Testing One},
                description={We are Testing One}
}


\newglossaryentry{pref1:testone2}{
                type=type1,
                name={Testing One Too},
                description={We are Testing One as well}
}


\newglossaryentry{pref2:testtwo}{
                type=type2,
                name={Testing Two},
                description={Now we are adding to Two}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref2:testtwo2}{
                type=type2,
                name={Testing Two Too},
                description={Now we are adding to Two too}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref3:testthree}{
                type=type3,
                name={Testing Three},
                description={Finally Three}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref3:testthree2}{
                type=type3,
                name={Testing Three Too},
                description={Finally Three Too}
}


\begin{document}

\gls{pref3:testthree2} and \hfill\\
\gls{pref2:testtwo}

\printglossary[type=type3]
\printglossary[type=type1]
\printglossary[type=type2] 

\end{document}
```

I'm getting three  glossaries in the correct order, but:

1. only {pref3:testthree2} is being referenced
2. {pref3:testthree2} is being referenced by ALL types

Command to generate PDF is: PDFlatex + PDFlatex + makeglossaries + makeglossaries + PDFlatex + PDFlatex.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've used the same file extension `ntn` for each glossary. Change them to `{ntn1}`, `{ntn2}` and `{ntn3}` and retry.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Can you change your comment to an answer so I can tick it as solved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you've used the same file extension for each glossary. This means they're being overwritten by `makeindex` and the same file is being read for each `\printglossary`.

Here's your edited MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=red
}

\usepackage[nopostdot,acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,nomain]{glossaries}

\newglossary[tld]{type1}{pref1}{ntn1}{Title One}
\newglossary[tld]{type2}{pref2}{ntn2}{Title Two}
\newglossary[tld]{type3}{pref3}{ntn3}{Title Three}
\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{pref1:testone}{
                type=type1,
                name={Testing One},
                description={We are Testing One}
}


\newglossaryentry{pref1:testone2}{
                type=type1,
                name={Testing One Too},
                description={We are Testing One as well}
}


\newglossaryentry{pref2:testtwo}{
                type=type2,
                name={Testing Two},
                description={Now we are adding to Two}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref2:testtwo2}{
                type=type2,
                name={Testing Two Too},
                description={Now we are adding to Two too}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref3:testthree}{
                type=type3,
                name={Testing Three},
                description={Finally Three}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref3:testthree2}{
                type=type3,
                name={Testing Three Too},
                description={Finally Three Too}
}


\begin{document}

\gls{pref3:testthree2} and \hfill\\
\gls{pref2:testtwo}

\printglossary[type=type3]
\printglossary[type=type1]
\printglossary[type=type2] 

\end{document}
```

An alternative is to use the starred form of `\newglossary` which constructs the extensions from the glossary label. For example

```
\newglossary*{type1}{Title One}
```

is equivalent to

```
\newglossary[type1-glg]{type1}{type1-gls}{type1-glo}{Title One}
```

This can be useful if you have a lot of glossaries as then you don't have to keep track of all the extensions. Since the glossary label has to be unique, this will ensure that the glossary file extensions don't clash with each other.

Updated MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    filecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=red
}

\usepackage[nopostdot,acronym,toc,section=chapter,style=indexgroup,nomain]{glossaries}

\newglossary*{type1}{Title One}
\newglossary*{type2}{Title Two}
\newglossary*{type3}{Title Three}
\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{pref1:testone}{
                type=type1,
                name={Testing One},
                description={We are Testing One}
}


\newglossaryentry{pref1:testone2}{
                type=type1,
                name={Testing One Too},
                description={We are Testing One as well}
}


\newglossaryentry{pref2:testtwo}{
                type=type2,
                name={Testing Two},
                description={Now we are adding to Two}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref2:testtwo2}{
                type=type2,
                name={Testing Two Too},
                description={Now we are adding to Two too}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref3:testthree}{
                type=type3,
                name={Testing Three},
                description={Finally Three}
}

\newglossaryentry{pref3:testthree2}{
                type=type3,
                name={Testing Three Too},
                description={Finally Three Too}
}


\begin{document}

\gls{pref3:testthree2} and \hfill\\
\gls{pref2:testtwo}

\printglossary[type=type3]
\printglossary[type=type1]
\printglossary[type=type2] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. `\makeglossaries` only needs to be called once, right?

Comment: Also, I can do away with the prefixes too right? As long as I specify the type

Comment: @tetris11 Only one `\makeglossaries` is needed in the document and only one `makeglossaries` system call to process all three glossaries. For prefixes, do you mean the prefix to the labels? All labels must be unique across all glossaries, so prefixes are useful to avoid label clashes (for example, `pref1:testone` and `pref2:testone`). You can't have both a `testone` in `type1` and a `testone` in `type2`, but you can have a `testone1` in `type1` and a `testone2` in `type2`.