# How do I make a nested glossary?

Tags: pdftex, lists, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I would like to make a nested glossary. For example, there may be subsections for Latin and Greek symbols, sorting is not needed. I tried using the 'parent/nodpostdesc' combination but the result is not great. The problem is likely to be the glossary style.

Anyway, I do not know how to do it, and I do not have enough time to read the documentation properly. Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

I attach what I tried to do, (as you can see the symbols are not shown and the 'titles' have a bad format):

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[symbols, style = long, sort = none]{glossaries-extra}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newglossaryentry{operators}{
    name={Operators},
    text={Greek letter},
    description={\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{matrix}
{
    name={\ensuremath{[\,]}},
    sort={matrix}, 
    description={Matrix},
    parent=operators
}


\newglossaryentry{vector} 
{
    name={\ensuremath{\{\,\}}},
    sort={vector}, 
    description={Vector},
    parent=operators
}


% ELEMENTS COORDINATES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newglossaryentry{elementcoordinates}{
    name={Element coordinates},
    text={Greek letter},
    description={\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{gir} 
{
    name={\ensuremath{x_r\,y_r\,z_r}},
    sort={gir}, 
    description={Global interpolated coordinates of rebar},
    parent = elementcoordinates
}

\newglossaryentry{v:globint:r} 
{
    name={\ensuremath{\{x_r\}}},
    sort={v:globint:r}, 
    description={Vector containing the global interpolated coordinates of a rebar},
    parent = elementcoordinates
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall
    \printunsrtglossary[title = {List of Symbols}]
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I found a good resource, [Gallery: Logical Glossary Divisions (type vs group vs parent)](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/index.php?label=logicaldivisions)

I would like to do exactly what is shown here (see the example 'Example Document: Custom Group Blocks'). The problem is that it seems I can produce something similar only using bib2glos. All my entries are defined in a TeX file though.

I found also this post [LaTeX forum ⇒ General ⇒ glossaries | Split Glossary into Latin and Greek Symbols](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=14473). It looks like this guy managed to do it without using bib2gls, however, I tried to compile the code myself and it did not print any glossary...

Comment: It sounds like you want to have multiple glossaries. For a thorough description of this, you will have to read the documentation, though you can find examples here and elsewhere online (e.g. in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/323314/48973)).

Comment: I think multiple glossaries are different because the titles would be of the same dimension (i may be wrong). I want an effect similar to \section and \subsection.  Thanks anyway!